# How to recover a partition accidently deleted with fdisk (Linux)?

Tags: linux, vmware, fedora

I am using FC6 in VMware, I accidently deleted my partition by using `fdisk`, it told me that after the restart, the partition will be deleted. Now I lost all my important data in that drive. What are the ways to recover this partition?

**UPDATE**

I installed `teskdisk`, after running it I did following

1. After disk selection I got that `/dev.hdd/` is the drive that I am looking for. So I select it.
2. After that I go to the "Analyze" option.
3. After a quick search it found all files I am looking for.

Now can you please tell me how to recover this partition?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending how you managed to delete your partition, [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) might be able to recover it. It's available on countless live-cd including:

- [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page)
- [RecoveryIsPossible](http://www.tux.org/pub/people/kent-robotti/looplinux/rip/)
- [Trinity Rescue Kit](http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?wpid=1&front_id=12)
- [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/)

Comment: +1 for testdisk. That app has saved countless Gb of data for me.

Comment: Hi avelldiroll, I installed teskdisk, after running it I did following

1). After disk selection I got that /dev.hdd/ is the drive that I am looking for. So I select it.

2).  After that I go in to Analyze option.

3). After quick search it found all files I am looking for.

4). Now can you please tell me how to recover this partition?

Comment: Their should be an option to save the recovered partition table. The testdisk website has a lot of documantation. This link should describe your use-case: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps I followed to recover partition.

1. [Download](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) and extract TestDisk linux version.
2. Run testdisk_static executable residing in linux folder.
3. Select Option [NO_LOG], After that I got drive selection. I select the drive I deleted.
4. Select [EFI_GPT] option, After that select [QUICK SEARCH] option
5. Select [WRITE] option, restart computer and I recovered my partition.