# How can I recover an encrypted Linux partition after resizing, when the volume shows up as "Unknown"?

Tags: linux, partitioning, disk-encryption, fdisk

I had followed the [this how-to on reducing the size of an encrypted (LUKS) partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions).

Everything went fine until the `fdisk` session. In the disk utility, the volume shows up as "Unknown" as opposed to "Encrypted" and `cryptsetup` doesn't recognize it (`luksDump` shows nothing.) Resizing it to use the same number of sectors as before didn't fix the problem.

I found this question: [How to recover a partition accidently deleted with fdisk (Linux)?](https://superuser.com/questions/57240/how-to-recover-a-partition-accidently-deleted-with-fdisk-linux) – it suggests using `testdisk`.

Would `testdisk` be likely to be able to restore my partition? If so, how do I recover a lost LUKS partition? If not, what else might work?

Answer (score 0):

testdisk ended up working. The issue was that fdisk starts partitions at the first head and sector in a cylinder. Any tool that can start at an arbitrary offset should also work.

A messed-up partition table is not data loss.