# Unable to detect NTFS partitions on Linux

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, multi-boot, ntfs

I have Windows and Ubuntu installed on a SSD and my other data on a separate HDD. Ubuntu (and Fedora before this) does not detect the NTFS partitions on the SSD. The disk does show up in GParted and by running `fdisk -l` but the partitions are not recognized. I am able to access the partitions on Windows. I ran `chkdsk` on them in Windows and no errors were found.

Actually, the HDD had a bootable partition of Windows on it and my boot loader was defaulting to that one instead of the SSD and so I deleted the EFI and Windows partitions from the HDD. I suspect that is causing the above problem but I am not sure how to fix it.

**EDIT**

Output of `fdisk -l` is as follows

```
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 61.89 MiB, 64901120 bytes, 126760 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 248.76 MiB, 260841472 bytes, 509456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 81.26 MiB, 85209088 bytes, 166424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 45.86 MiB, 48087040 bytes, 93920 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 43.63 MiB, 45748224 bytes, 89352 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 284 KiB, 290816 bytes, 568 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000LM024 HN-M
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F7D37684-4A80-4CDA-9811-94DD17B5242F

Device      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda3  262178 1953525134 1953262957 931.4G Microsoft LDM data



Disk /dev/sdb: 223.57 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: CT240BX500SSD1  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F3C25BEA-BF37-4371-80FA-841588B6416B

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sdb2     206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb3     239616 398465225 398225610 189.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb4  467800064 468858879   1058816   517M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sdb5  398467072 467800063  69332992  33.1G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

The drive in question is `/dev/sda`

**EDIT 2**
Previously, the partitions were visible but now it shows just this -

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `not recognized`? Why didn't you attach the `fdisk -l` output?

Comment: "I deleted the EFI and Windows partitions from the HDD" you've deleted the partitions from the disk, how do you expect your OS to recognize something that doesn't exist? You might be able to [recover the partitions using testdisk](https://superuser.com/questions/57240/how-to-recover-a-partition-accidently-deleted-with-fdisk-linux).

Comment: @mashuptwice I just deleted EFI and the Windows system partition. There were other partitions that were at the time being recognized by Windows after the deletion.

Comment: @TomYan I've updated the question and attached the output.

Comment: @Yashbhatt I suspect that you are talking about /dev/sda3, which seems to be a LDM partition. Was this a windows 7 installation? Try to mount it with `sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda3 /some/directory/to/mount/it/to`, if that fails, you might have some luck restoring it with [ldmtool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427372/windows-spanned-disks-ldm-restoration-with-linux)

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Disk Management on Windows.

Comment: @mashuptwice I need access to the data. No partitions or the drive show up in File Explorer or Nautilus.

Comment: @Yashbhatt did you try any of the mentioned possible solutions, like using `mount` or to recover the deleted partitions with `testdisk` or using `ldmtool`?

Comment: @mashuptwice Yes mounting did not work. It just says `not a valid NTFS partition`. Currently, `testdisk` is analyzing the disk.

Comment: Okay I was able to recover the partitions using testdisk!

Comment: Glad it worked!